# How to search a multifield fully contained by the keyword with solr?

Tags: solr

Is it possible for solr to search a multifield which is contained by the keyword

e.g

```
keyword: "I have a problem"
```

search for

```
fields:[
   "a problem"
]
```

but not for

```
fields:[
  "a wrong problem"
]
```

is there any idea about this?

Comment: try using ShingleFilterFactory... https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ShingleFilterFactory

Comment: did this resolve your problem?